# jquery fadetoggle on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

now I read all fadeToggle articles but can't get it working:

I select different divs (para1, para 2 etc.) by toggle (with css .hidden {display: none;}) by dropdown and it works perfect. But I want to fade the divs smooth in. As soon as I change the .toggle to .fadeToggle (or fadeIn) the output is completely mixed up.

Has anybody an idea why and what I make wrong?

The html is:

```
<div id="dropdown">
<select id="tables" name="tables[]" onchange="changeHandler()">
<option value="defcont" selected>Select some content</option>
<option value="cont1">Content 1</option>
<option value="cont2">Content 2</option>
<option value="cont3">Content 3</option>
</select>
</div><!-- DROPDOWN -->


<div id="paragraphs">
<div id="paradefault">This is the default content without selection</div>
<div id="para1" class="hidden">You see now content 1.</div>
<div id="para2" class="hidden">You see now content 2.</div>
<div id="para3" class="hidden">You see now content 3?.</div>
</div><!-- paragraphs -->
```

The Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tables').change(function(e){
$('#paradefault').toggle($('option[value="defcont"]:selected',this).length > 0);
$('#para1').toggle($('option[value="cont1"]:selected',this).length > 0);
$('#para2').toggle($('option[value="cont2"]:selected',this).length > 0);
$('#para3').toggle($('option[value="cont3"]:selected',this).length > 0);
});
</script>
```

The most near article is this: ['fadeToggle' multiple div tags via drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179794/fadetoggle-multiple-div-tags-via-drop-down-menu) - but just with toggle and not dafeToggle.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: you want to toggle fade for all of them at the same time or just one by one?

Comment: One by one. When I drop down on cont2, para 2 should fade in. It works bud doesn't fade. When I change -toggle to .fadeToggle it shows me all other paragraphs in a weird mix :)

Comment: The jsfidle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nRxq5/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/uvT76/
I would have to fix the "jumpiness" but perhaps it's on the right track.

html:

```
<div id="dropdown">
    <select id="tables" name="tables[]" onchange="changeHandler()">
        <option value="defcont" selected>Select some content</option>
        <option value="cont1">Content 1</option>
        <option value="cont2">Content 2</option>
        <option value="cont3">Content 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="paragraphs">
    <div id="paraDefault">This is the default content without selection</div>
    <div id="para_1" class="hidden">You see now content 1.</div>
    <div id="para_2" class="hidden">You see now content 2.</div>
    <div id="para_3" class="hidden">You see now content 3.</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var opts = $("#tables option");
$('#tables').on("change", fader);

function fader(e) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
        case ("defcont"):
            var others = String("#paragraphs div[id^='para_']");
            $(others).each(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(250, 0);
            });
            $(others).promise().done(function () {
                $(others).css("display", "none");
                $("#paraDefault").fadeTo(1000, 1);
            });
            break;
        default:
            var showPara = String("para_" + e.target.value.substr(e.target.value.length - 1));
           // alert(showPara);
            var sel = String("#paragraphs div[id!=" + showPara + "]");
            $(sel).each(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(250, 0);
            });
            $(sel).promise().done(function () {
                $(sel).css("display", "none");
                $(String("#" + showPara)).fadeTo(1000, 1);
            });
    }
}
```

css:

```
div[id^='para_'] {
    display:none;
}
#dropdown {
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Comment: Glad you like it, Chris.  If you want me to fix the jumpiness for you, let me know, and I'll be happy to.  If it solves your issue, I'd appreciate it if you'd click the check next to the answer.  :-)

Comment: @itsmikem what was the fix for the jumpiness?

Comment: @Drai I'll have to go back and review my code.  It might be a bit before I get to it...